# VBA Run-time error.'1004': Copy area and the paste area are not the same size

Tags: excel, vba

I am debugging a VBA macro and I am getting an error message "Run-time error.'1004':
The information cannot be pasted because the Copy area and the paste area are not the same size and shape."

Here's my code :

```
   Sub Test()
Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Dim m As Long, i As Long, n As Long
Dim Val As Variant

Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
n = 1
m = 1
Val = s1.Range("B1").Value

For i = 1 To Columns.Count
    If s2.Cells(1, i).Value = Val Then
        s2.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=s1.Range("B4")
        m = m + 1
        
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Please help

Sheet 1:
[image: Sheet 1]

Sheet 2:
[image: Sheet2]

Edit:

I tried INDEX/MATCH as BigBen had suggested and it worked
Here's the formula : =INDEX(Sheet2!$A2:$E2,MATCH(Sheet1!$B$1,Sheet2!$A$1:$E$1,0))

But if someone could help me with the VBA code it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You can only copy an *entire* column into the first row (B1). It won't fit if you try to copy into any other row. But I'm guessing that you don't actually need to copy the *entire* column, and you probably don't need to loop through every single column in the worksheet (`Columns.Count`).

Comment: I need to copy 5 cells in the column actually. Is there any way to select a range? I also need to loop through all the cells in a row till a blank cell appears. I am trying to check if the value in sheet 1 B1 is present in sheet 2 row 1. If yes then I want to copy the 5 cells included in the column. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Change `s2.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn` to the range you want to copy?

Comment: How will I change the "i" if I fix the range?

Comment: Maybe explain the setup/format of sheet2 a bit more. Or add a sample screenshot.

Comment: I am unable to add a table. Is there any other way to show you my sheet 2?

Comment: Add a screenshot and we can edit it in.

Comment: I added screenshots of both my sheets. Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like you can do this with a formula by the way. Is VBA a necessity?

Comment: Will I be able to copy a column using Formula? If so then it would be great. I would also like to know if it can be done by VBA. I can make a comparison for my project then.

Comment: INDEX/MATCH should do the trick.

Comment: I had actually tried index match but I was getting Value Error